# How do you cast an NSMenuItem.representedObject to a Swift Protocol?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I'm storing an instance of a Swift struct in an `NSMenuItem's` `representedObject` and running into some problems. The struct conforms to a basic protocol and I would like to cast the `representedObject` to that protocol. When I attempt to do that, my `guard` fails every time. If I cast to the struct type, then there is no problem.

Below is a very basic example that illustrates the problem. Is there a way to store an instance of `Person` in an `NSMenuItem` but to then retrieve it as a `FullyNamed`?

**Edit 1**

I quickly noticed that if I use a `class` instead of a `struct` then it works as expected. Why is that?

*macOS 10.15, Xcode 11 Beta 5*

```
import Cocoa

protocol FullyNamed {
  var fullName:String { get }
}

struct Person : FullyNamed {
  let firstName:String
  let lastName:String

  var fullName:String { "\(firstName) \(lastName)" }
}

// Create an NSMenuItem with an instance of Person() as the representedObject.

let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title:"Johnny Appleseed", action:nil, keyEquivalent:"")
menuItem.representedObject = Person(firstName:"Johnny", lastName:"Appleseed")

// Somewhere else in the code, retrieve the menu item's representedObject
// as a known protocol type. Unfortunately, this fails.

guard let nameable = menuItem.representedObject as? FullyNamed else {
  fatalError("Error, could not cast to FullyNamed")
}

// Execution does not reach this point as the guard above fails.
print(nameable.fullName)
```

Comment: Probably due to https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871

Comment: In which case the workaround would be to cast it as `menuItem.representedObject as AnyObject as? FullyNamed`

Comment: Dan, you appear to be correct. If you'd like to move your comment into an answer then I can accept it.